# Getting all the strings that comes after specific character python

Tags: python, list, slice

Getting strings that comes after a character which is '$' and store them as lowercase strings in a list.
For example:

```
string = "apple $is a $tasty fruiit and $CHEAP"
['is', 'tasty', 'cheap']
```

I tried

```
string.lower()
lst  = []
lst.append(string.lower().split("$",1)[1:])
return lst
```

**EDIT**
It also should end before a number or special character like
string = "apple $is a $tasty fruit and $CHEAP#chs"
['is', 'tasty', 'cheap']
where it shouldn't be cheap#chs
Can someone help?

Comment: regex would give one possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex:

```
import re

s = "apple $is a $tasty fruiit and $CHEAP"

re.findall(r'(?<=\$)(.+?)\b', s.lower()))
```

Yields:

```
['is', 'tasty', 'cheap']
```

Answer (score 0):

[`string.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) returns a new lowercase string and doesn't do anything to the original. One possible way to do this is to split your string by spaces, and check if a word [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) "$":

```
string = "apple $is a $tasty fruiit and $CHEAP"
result = [s[1:] for s in string.lower().split() if s.startswith('$')]

print(result)
# ['is', 'tatsy', 'cheap']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s1='apple $is a $tasty fruiit and $CHEAP'
lst=s1.split()
sample=[]
for i in lst:
    if '$' in i:
        sample.append(i[1:].lower())
print(sample)
```

This one gives op as `['is', 'tasty', 'cheap']`. Regex is simple though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use The [count()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm) method, as follows:

```
starting_point = 0
Lst = []
for _ in range(string.count('$')):
    starting_point += string[starting_point+1:].index('$')+1
    Lst.append(string[starting_point:].split()[0].split('$')[1].lower())
```

and the output would be:

```
['is', 'tasty', 'cheap']
```